# Magento duplicate attriubte set new attributes not showing in front end

Tags: php, magento, attributes, admin

1. Duplicated attriubte set for new product line.
2. Attributes set show in backend and front end.
3. Created new attribute and added to attribute set.
4. New attribute show's in back end but not front end.
5. If I add the new attribute to the origonal set that was duplicated the new attribute will now show on the front end for the product assoiated with the duplicated attribute group.

So basicly A new attribute added to a duplicate set won't show on the front end until its added to the attribute set that  was duplicated.

I've checked to make sure the attribute is visable on front end etc and tried it several times checking the settings.

The goal is to be able to duplicate a attribute set and add new attributes for different product types. Then call the folder by id and display the assoiated attributes.

I've called the attribute group by ID (spec's). This code is working.

```
<?php   
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$attributeGroupCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_group_collection');
$product = $this->getProduct();

foreach ($attributeGroupCollection as $attributeGroup) {
    $attributeGroup->getAttributeGroupId();       
$attributeSpecs = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
    ->setAttributeGroupFilter(41);    

} 
?>
```

Help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: what is "the folder" ?

Comment: the folder I"m adding attributes to in the attribute set is 'Product Specifications'

Comment: I'm not sure if this is just how magento works. Do I need to make a new folder/attribute group  in the duplicate attribute set if I want to add new attributes to the folder/group?  Then add anther custom call to the folder/group to be displayed the same way? This is unfortunate as it means for several product types I'll need to create several queries and the user won't be able to set up a new attribute set until the query is written into the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was is magento creates a new id for each new group folder in the new duplicated attribute set (makes sense). I was calling by ID for the group and as a result will only show attributes in the origional folder (weird) even if the product was assoicated with the new attribute set.  What I did was get the current attribute set id and then sort out the attribute groups by name so even if the attribute sets are coppied as long as the folde has the name it will display in the custom loop displaying the attributes. Here is my working code:

```
    $attributeSetModel = Mage::getModel("eav/entity_attribute_set");
    $attributeSetModel->load($product->getAttributeSetId());
    $attributeSetName  = $attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetName();
    $attributeSetID  = $attributeSetModel->getAttributeSetID();

$groups = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group')
->getResourceCollection()
->setAttributeSetFilter($attributeSetID)
->setSortOrder()
->load();

$attributeCodes = array();
foreach ($groups as $group) {
echo $groupName          = $group->getAttributeGroupName();
$groupId            = $group->getAttributeGroupId();

if (strpos($groupName , 'Specifications') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
    $specificationsNum = $groupId;
};
if (strpos($groupName , 'eatures') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
    $prodfeaturesNum = $groupId;
};
}
//echo $specifications;
$specifications = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
->setAttributeGroupFilter($specificationsNum); 
$prodfeatures = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
->setAttributeGroupFilter($prodfeatures);
```

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating an attribute set is duplicating at a time (the moment when you click the button). If you want to add an attribute in both attribute sets, you need to create it in both, for that, you just need to create your attribute and drop it in the section you want to have it linked to (what you call "folder"). If you want to do it programmatically. You need to create an observer that will be fired after the attribute set is saved and that will add the attribute to the duplicated attribute set. I would not advise to do so because it means that you need to enter the ID of the attribute set duplicated and it can be tricky thing when it comes to pushing the development to the production. I am sure there is a workaround for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks the problem I'm having is I only want the attribute show up in the duplicate attribute set/duplicate folder. How ever if I add the new attribute to the duplicate folder it will not show up in the front end unless it is in the original as well.  So I have to have the attributes in both folders to show up? I only want this in one folder but it won't show in the front end unless its in both.

Comment: where do you want to display it in frontend ?

Comment: I created a loop that pulls the folder by id on the product page and lists all the attributes from the folder specifications. In the duplicated folder the new attribute won't display for the product assoiated with the duplicate attriubte set. It shows the attributes that where in the folder before the attribute set was copyed but not the new attributes added. Its weird that the old attributes show up for the new product assoicated with the attriubte set but when I add a new it dosn't show up in the front end.

Comment: `<?php   
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

$attributeGroupCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_group_collection');
$product = $this->getProduct();

foreach ($attributeGroupCollection as $attributeGroup) {
    $attributeGroup->getAttributeGroupId();        
$attributeSpecs = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
    ->setAttributeGroupFilter(41);    
} 
?> 

<?php  foreach ($attributeFeatures as $attribute): ?> 
<?php echo '<div class="spec '.$attribute->getAttributeCode().'">'.$attribute->getStoreLabel().'</div>' ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>`

Comment: where do you want to display in the frontend ?

Comment: It is displayed on the product page. In a custom built area.

Comment: Thanks, I belive I can't do it this way as each time the folder is duplicated it creates a new id. So calling by id means I will need to query for each attribute set instance of attribute group with new attributes in this section.  Unless I can query for the name under the current attriubte set.